# Gnome and Gdm doesn't recognize my password

Tags: arch-linux, gnome, gdm

I installed Archlinux as Virtualbox's guest on Windows. After installation, I can not log in through GDM, though it lists my user name, and the root account doesn't work either. The error info is:

```
Sorry, that didn't work. Please try again.
```

Then I try to log in through command line, and `startx` manually. This time it works, however, whenever I need to input my password in terminal, it doesn't recognize either.

How do I solve this? I am using Gnome 3.

Comment: Are you using a non qwerty keyboard ? And perhaps didn't configure the keyboard layout for X ?

Comment: Have you tried typing out your password somewhere where you can see it and making sure that you're typing what you think you're typing? You might have a slightly different keyboard layout set up under the VM